# Need to calculate the Total of the Two Integer Values

Tags: c#, ado.net, int

```
private void cbService1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = "Data Source=DELL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Salon Primik; Integrated Security = True";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(str);

            string Name = cbService1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            cn.Open();
            string Sql = "select Amount from Service where Name='" + Name + "'";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, cn);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                lblService1.Text = dr["Amount"].ToString();
                int i1 = Convert.ToInt32(lblService1.Text);
                total(i1,0);

            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }

private void cbService2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = "Data Source=DELL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Salon Primik; Integrated Security = True";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(str);

            string Name = cbService2.SelectedValue.ToString();
            cn.Open();
            string Sql = "select Amount from Service where Name='" + Name + "'";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, cn);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                lblService2.Text = dr["Amount"].ToString();
                int i2 = Convert.ToInt32(lblService2.Text);
                total(0,i2);
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }

        private int total(int i,int i2)
        {
            int Total = i + i2;
            string total = Total.ToString();
            lblTotal.Text = total;
```

Comment: what is your question here

Comment: I need to calculate the two int values (i and i2) .

Comment: int i1 = Convert.ToInt32(lblService1.Text);
and 
int i2 = Convert.ToInt32(lblService2.Text);

needs to add and total has to be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something from your method:

```
private int total(int i,int i2)
{
    int Total = i + i2;
    return Total;
}
```

And the set in

```
private void cbService2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your other code
    lblTotal.Text = total(i1, i2).ToString();
}
```

Or if you want to change labels from within the method and not return anything, change it to

```
private void total (int i1, int i2)
```

Comment: i2 is available in cbService1_SelectedIndexChanged method. And Still having trouble calculating.

Comment: In lblTotal.Text = total(i1, i2).ToString(); i1 and i2 are there to mark 2 integer values you need to pass as parameters to your total() method. This is basic stuff, maybe you should read some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code to this on both event respectedly.

```cs
lblService1.Text = dr["Amount"].ToString();
int i1 = Convert.ToInt32(lblService1.Text);
int i2 = Convert.ToInt32(lblService2.Text);
total(i1,i2);

lblService2.Text = dr["Amount"].ToString();
int i1 = Convert.ToInt32(lblService1.Text);
int i2 = Convert.ToInt32(lblService2.Text);
total(i1,i2);
```

SQL SUM() function is also a good try.